# How to trim transparent pixels in svg?

Tags: svg, transparency

I need option similar to what photoshop has

[image: trim transparent pixels photoshop]

for svg files.

What is the best way to achieve that and in which program?

I am also considering manually editing .svg file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can

1. Select everything that should be included in the SVG Select Objects
2. -> Artboards -> Fit Artboard to Bounds

Answer (score 2):

You don't have that in Illustrator. To trim an SVG in illustrator, just use the  Artboard tool to adjust the artboard to the edges of your svg.

Also, you can just open your SVG in a text editor and manually change the viewbox size to trim the svg down. The viewbox is pretty much the same thing as a clipping mask.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I thought there was some better way do it though.

Comment: Not that I have found. That seems to be the easiest way to trim pixels or whitespace before export in illustrator.

Comment: Actually there is better solution! Go to Object > Artboards > Fit to Artwork Bounds. That way artwork is the same size as the object we are working on. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Ahh, nice find. Never realized there was a shortcut to auto trim the artboard.